# strange behaviour when I click on a newpage in gridview acts like I have clicked a row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

first my html

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            AllowPaging="True" datakeynames="Reservation_ID,Excursion_ID"
            onpageindexchanging="GridViewCustomers_PageIndexChanging"
            onrowcommand="GridViewCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged" 
             BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" >

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Reservation_ID" HeaderText="РЕЗ. №" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"  HeaderText="Име на Екскурзия" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Reservation_TotalAmount"  HeaderText="Сума по резервацията" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Excursion_ID" Visible="false" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReservationDate" HeaderText="Дата на заминаване" />

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Имена на Туристи">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("TouristName") %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# (Container.ItemIndex+1)+"."+ Container.DataItem  %><br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

So in the code you will se that on a click on select button I get the value od datakeyna and redirect the user to another page. The problem is that when I click page 2 of my gridview i'm redirected to the other page as if I have selected one row.

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lstUserReservations.AddRange(lstUserReservations);
        this.lstUserReservations.AddRange(lstUserReservations);
        this.lstUserReservations.AddRange(lstUserReservations);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            User_Reservation trr = new User_Reservation();
            lstUserReservations = new List<User_Reservation>();
            lstUserReservations = LoadReservationsForUser();
            GridViewCustomers.DataSource = lstUserReservations;
            GridViewCustomers.DataBind();
        }

    }

    protected void GridViewCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,  GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

    {  int indexer = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); 
                   Session["еxcursion_id"] = this.GridViewCustomers.DataKeys[indexer].Values["Excursion_ID"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("ReservationInfo.aspx");

    }
    protected void GridViewCustomers_PageIndexChanging(object sender,
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        this.GridViewCustomers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
         this.GridViewCustomers.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Yousee that I have

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight code you have to take care of. If you are changing the paging, then check if you have clicked the paging and return if you have or else select the row. Also, when you change the paging, the `RowCommand` event works first and after that `PageIndexChanging` event.

protected void GridViewCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,  GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

```
{  
    if(e.CommandName == "Page")
        return;
    int indexer = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); 
    Session["еxcursion_id"] = this.GridViewCustomers.DataKeys[indexer].Values["Excursion_ID"].ToString();
    Response.Redirect("ReservationInfo.aspx");

}
```

Let me know if this had worked for you.